# Can't import bert.tokenization

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp

I am using Google Colab and the following import doesn't work somehow:

```
from bert.tokenization import FullTokenizer
```

I am getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bert.tokenization'
```

I tried to install bert by running the following command:

```
!pip install  --upgrade bert
```

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found it:

```
!pip install bert-tensorflow
```

Answer (score 4):

install :
`pip install bert-for-tf2`

then import,

`from bert import bert_tokenization
 BertTokenizer = bert_tokenization.FullTokenizer`

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'bert_tokenization' from 'bert' (unknown location)

Comment: did you install `bert-for-tf2` ?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing this problem with TensorFlow 2.0 and the bert-for-tf2 library, I found out that I was missing some files after using pip3 install. I've posted my solution here:

https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/638#issuecomment-592488730

Answer (score 0):

or you may use previous version of BERT to avoid further complications (Atleast for now)

```
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
!pip install bert-tensorflow
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from datetime import datetime
import bert
from bert import run_classifier
from bert import optimization
from bert import tokenization
```

Answer (score 0):

In tf1:

```
!pip install bert-tokenizer
```

```
import bert_tokenizer as tokenization

tokenization.tokenizer.FullTokenizer
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by uninstalling and installing using both pip3 and pip.

```
!pip3  uninstall -y bert-tensorflow 
!pip  uninstall -y bert-tensorflow

!pip3  install bert-tensorflow 
!pip install bert-tensorflow
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
!pip install bert-tokenizer
```

to use:

```
import bert_tokenizer as tokenizer
```

---

**NOT `import bert_tokenization as tokenization` !!!**

Answer (score -1):

You might try this:

```
!pip install bert-tensorflow

!pip install  --upgrade bert

!pip install tokenization


from bert import tokenization  
from **bert.tokenization.bert_tokenization** import **FullTokenizer** 


tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file=vocab_file, do_lower_case=do_lower_case)
```